# What is the merit of prepared statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic-sql

After I read about prepared statement,I can set prepared statement like following.
It worked, but I haven't understood what is the merit of prepared statment. because I wonder what is the merit beyond normal sql in prepared statment ?

```
SELECT CONCAT("SELECT *
"FROM table",
"Where snapshot_day >= cast(now() as date) - interval 9 day ",
"And type in ('Daily') ",
"GROUP BY 1") INTO @myquery;
SELECT @myquery;
PREPARE stmt FROM @myquery;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

If someone has opinion, please let me know

Comment: That might depend on the use case, but as the given example does not contain any user-supplied content, this might not be a security topic

Comment: *what is the merit of prepared statment.* Some parts of SQL query cannot be parametrized (for example, tablenames) - only dynamic SQL allows to execute such queries. An example of the real task - expand all VARCHAR columns lengths in all database tables till VARCHAR(255)...